# How to exclude a few words from a string field returned from an api response in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native, api

im trying to exclude a few words from an api string that was returned. I did research on this and saw that people were using REGEX(regular expressions) for this. I tried to copy what they did, however, with api responses, it adds another level of difficulty to it and is not quite the same.

[image]

Is there a way to exclude the "Messari Daily Brief" from the api and include everything else? Im trying to grab everything from that title field but the Messari Daily Text.

I tried store the string like this

```
const title = this.props.newsItems.title;
```

Then I tried to do the regex:

```
const extractedString = '/Messari Daily Brief /'
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just iterate through the items and replace that string with empty  string.
your items will have now everything except the title does not contain that string(**Messari Daily Brief**)

```
const items = this.props.newsItems.map(item => 
      ({ ...item, title: item.title.replace('Messari Daily Brief', '') }));
```